# How to retrieve a Has One relation in view in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relation

I have a relationship where a user has many emails, and an email belongs to one user. I define it like this in my message model :

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','sender_id','id');
}
```

Here is my controller :

```
 $sender_name = Message::with('users')->get();
 return view('admin.message.read',compact('message','sender_name'));
```

In my view, I do something like this :

```
 @foreach($sender_name as $sender_names)
  @php(
  dd($sender_name)
  )
    {{$sender_name->name}}
 @endforeach
```

So, here I have 2 questions:

1. How do I retrieve the relation I defined in my view? Currently, I get an error that this property does not exist on collection !!!
2. Do I need to define the opposite relation in the user's model like this? :

```
    public function messages() {
        $this->hasOne('App\Message','id','sender_id');
    }
```

Here is the code around the view :

```
<div class="media-body">
    <h6 class="media-heading">{{$message->title}}</h6>
    <!-- sender name of Email-->
    <div class="letter-icon-title text-semibold">
        @foreach($sender_name as $sender_names)
            {{$sender_names->users->name}}
        @endforeach
    <!-- sender name of Email-->

    <!-- sender Email-->
        <a href="#">jira@diakultd.atlassian.net</a>
    </div>
    <!-- sender name of Email-->
</div>
<!-- body of Email-->
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" style="font-size: 40px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 50px; font-weight: 300;">   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /title -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to get the user who have added this message. So for that you are fetching messages through its model and adding up users in it through relation, that's why you need to define it in messages model.

To use it in views you can use

```
@foreach($sender_name as $sender_names)
    {{$sender_names->users->name}}
@endforeach
```

To study about relations Laravel has a good documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: but unfortunately there is nothing for relations and how to get them in view like a real life example in that documentation

Comment: and there is some thing else now that i  have do it it shows the user name but like 10 times :| shows as number of user has send emails for example if user send 100 emails it shows the user name 100 times any idea ?

Comment: As per your current code it will print user name for each message. How you want to show it now?

Comment: i just want to show the user name that sent this email and ofc it should be once in my message table i have a field as sender_id which gets the user id that is currently logged in and the other part of code that you see in question

Comment: What I am getting is you want to show all messages for a single user right? If yes then you should fetch messages on the basis of users like User::with("messages")

Comment: kamal i am sorry if i exaplain badly no i dont wana show all message its a message that i want to show who is it from . its a single view of a message that says for example kamal send that

Comment: It will be more easier to understand if you can provide an screenshot.

Comment: i just edited the question and for further info just know that its the email(message) view that i want to show the information like title of message  body of the message and sender of the message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183610/discussion-between-kamal-paliwal-and-farshad).

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
@foreach($sender_name as $sender_names)  
    {{$sender_names->users->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can try like that

```
@foreach($sender_name as $sender_names)  
    {{$sender_names->users->name}}
@endforeach
```

[see](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/eloquent-relationships-the-ultimate-guide/) this is good example of one to one relationship

Answer (score 0):

so here is what happened to me in view :
the foreach loops that people said was true but i had some other problem that i could do without foreach to show a sender id

```
public function show(Message $message)                                                                       
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     $sender_name = Message::with('users')->where('sender_id', $message->sender_id)->first();                 
        Message::with('users')->get();                                                                        
     return view('admin.message.read',compact('message','sender_name'));                                      
 }
```

and simple as that in view you print it

```
{{$sender_name->users->name}}
```

and like this you can print the name of the sender of the email